# PHP XML Element uses an @ symbol?

Tags: php, xml

Currently processing an XML document using PHP when an element when looped through uses an '@' symbol as seen:

```
 [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [name] => Files1
    )
```

Within the XML file this is displayed as :

```
  <Artifacts>
  <Artifact name="Files1">
```

My code currently to get the array with the "@" reported is the following:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file("Export.xml");
foreach($xml->Artifacts as $item){
    foreach($item->Artifact as $art){
        print_r ($art);
        exit();
```

I'm aiming to use a if statement to only grab the children from the XML file if the Artifact name is only certain things i.e Files1, Files3 and Files5. However with the "@attributes" this is throwing me off as you can't do:

```
if($art->@attributes->name...
```

Any help with how to use this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you not just use a proper xml parser like DOMDocument instead of that thing?

Comment: `$art['name']` should be all you need here. If that doesn’t help, then check http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php and the user comments on that site.

Comment: `if($art->{"@attributes"}->name)` should work, since you can access oddly named properties (ones with spaces, numbered, etc etc) using the `{}` syntax.